# Can't store multiple arguments with read -p in macOS terminal using bash

Tags: terminal, bash, text-input

I am trying to store words from an input as parameters with `read -p` as follows :

```bsh
    read -p "Enter your command: " cmd arg1 arg2
    echo "$cmd"
    echo "$arg1"
    echo "$arg2"
```

With this, $cmd contains all 3 inputs separated by spaces, $arg1 and $arg2 are empty. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the value of `$IFS`?

Comment: @nohillside it returns ':'

Comment: Set `IFS` back to its default. In other words, add the command `IFS=$' \t\n'` before the `read` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `IFS` is used by various commands. The safest thing to do is save the value, then restore when finished. Below is an example.

```
declare "IFS_BACKUP=$IFS"
IFS=$' \t\n'
read -p "Enter your command: " cmd arg1 arg2
IFS="$IFS_BACKUP"
echo "$cmd"
echo "$arg1"
echo "$arg2"
```

The documentation command `man bash` defines `IFS` as follows:

```
   IFS    The  Internal  Field  Separator  that is used for word splitting
          after expansion and to split lines  into  words  with  the  read
          builtin  command.   The  default  value  is  ``<space><tab><new-
          line>''.
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I will try understanding more about `IFS`